# SCR bridge control circuit

Tags: bridge-rectifier, scr, single-phase

I want to design a single phase 400V 1A power supply using mains (230VAC,50Hz). For which I plan to use a step up transformer which will step up to 400V and then an SCR Bridge rectifier to convert it into controlled/regulated DC supply.
How can I control the SCR bridge angle using Arduino or any other setup, how can I control the firing angle of SCRs? I searched the internet but couldn't found any implementation for SCR bridge control, most people have used 2 SCRs and 2 diodes. what would be the additional circuitry required for this setup?

Comment: " ... then an SCR Bridge rectifier to convert it into controlled/regulated DC supply." I think it is not the best idea, but it is up to you. What kind of supply, for what load ?

Answer (score 2):

First to start you do need a zero cross detector and then two optoSCR or optotriacs. Basically it is the same as if you would be doing dimmer circuit. The only difference is that you do need higher voltage rating for the SCR and optotriac.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWuy3U.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You have  [Arduino project](https://simple-circuit.com/arduino-220v-full-wave-controlled-bridge-rectifier/) for this. It is using gate transformers (GDT) instead of optocouplers, it's even better.

[image]

I don't like the zero cross detector as it is not galvanically isolated, but it can be changed. For example if you plan to order a custom 230/400V transformer, you could add a tertiary winding for Arduino PSU and you do ZC on this low voltage winding.

Alternatively you can place a 2nd small transformer for Arduino PSU and do ZC.

Comment: One bridge and 1 SCR would also do the job ?